# R - Scrape multiple url and wirte each data url in different excel data sheets

Tags: r, lapply, rvest, scrape

I'm trying to scrape different URL and write data in the same Excel's file but in a single page for each URL.

My code is this:

```
#install.packages("rvest")

library(XLConnect)
library(rvest)
{
 for(i in c("2086","2167","2204")) {
   url<-paste0("https://www.silversanz.com/producto/",i,)

}
 dades<-read_html(url)

 nom<-dades %>% html_nodes("h1.title") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
 preu<-dades %>% html_nodes("p.price--current") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()

 info<-as.data.frame(cbind(nom,preu))

 writeWorksheetToFile(file="C:/xxx.xxx.xlsx",
                   data=info,
                   sheet= "test",
                   clearSheets=TRUE
 )
}
```

I have two problems:

- This code doesn't work ->

  ```
   for(i in c("2086","2167","2204")) {
   url<-paste0("https://www.silversanz.com/producto/",i,)
  ```
- I don't know how to write one sheet for each url

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the brackets in the wrong way. The `for-loop` that you have written iterates over the numbers and saves the last one in `url`. Your `for-loop` instead should contain all of your code:

```
library(XLConnect)
library(rvest)

for(i in c("2086","2167","2204")) {

   url<-paste0("https://www.silversanz.com/producto/",i)

   dades<-read_html(url)

   nom<-dades %>% html_nodes("h1.title") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
   preu<-dades %>% html_nodes("p.price--current") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()

   info<-as.data.frame(cbind(nom,preu))

   writeWorksheetToFile(file="C:/xxx.xxx.xlsx",
                     data=info,
                     sheet= i,
                     clearSheets=TRUE)
}
```

As for the sheet, now that everything is in the loop, just use `i` as the sheet name in order to have one sheet per url.

Comment: Yeah, succesfull!! Thanks a lot, LyzandeR :-)

Comment: Happy to help :)